# Weld and Undertow under jakarta / javax namespaces

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, resteasy, weld, undertow

I am upgrading some of the libraries in my JEE application, hoping to solve a strange issue (see [JAX-RS integration test with Undertow failing in Jenkins but working locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69463489/jax-rs-integration-test-with-undertow-failing-in-jenkins-but-working-locally))

While upgrading restEasy, then Weld, my tests are failing because there are some "internal" compilation issues due to the change of namespace from `javax.servlet.ServletContext` to `jakarta.servlet.ServletContext` :

in my dependencies I have :

in weld-servlet-core 4.0.2.Final :

```
package org.jboss.weld.environment.undertow;

import io.undertow.servlet.ServletExtension;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletContext;
...

public class WeldServletExtension implements ServletExtension {

    @Override
    public void handleDeployment(DeploymentInfo deploymentInfo, ServletContext servletContext) {
...
}
}
```

and in undertow-servlet 2.2.7.Final :

```
package io.undertow.servlet;

import io.undertow.servlet.api.DeploymentInfo;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;

public interface ServletExtension {

    void handleDeployment(final DeploymentInfo deploymentInfo, final ServletContext servletContext);

}
```

This can't work, because WeldServletExtension actually does **not** implement ServletExtension in that setup : it uses a `jakarta.servlet.ServletContext`, while the interface requires the use of `javax.servlet.ServletContext`

`undertow-servlet:2.2.7.Final` is brought transitively by `resteasy-undertow:5.0.0.Beta1` (latest version available, from October 2021), and I add myself `weld-servlet-core:4.0.2.Final` (also latest version : from July 2021)

Looking at [ServletExtension in its main branch](https://github.com/undertow-io/undertow/blob/c910c9cc4bd3047c83a4e1d9411e0ec6076f289d/servlet/src/main/java/io/undertow/servlet/ServletExtension.java), Undertow is still using `javax.*` namespace, not `jakarta.*` - it hasn't been updated since 2014. So even if I were using Undertow latest version (2.2.12.Final), I would still have the issue

So I am a bit puzzled... what is the trick here ? can't we use Undertow once we upgrade to  RestEasy 5.x and use Weld ?

Comment: There is not currently a Jakarta REST 3.0 implementation of RESTEasy. Though this is coming, there is no official date ATM. I would say within a month there will at least be an alpha version.

Answer (score 1):

Undertow is shipping a special separate artifact that uses EE 9 namespaces.
It has a slightly different GAV - `io.undertow:undertow-servlet-jakartaee9:2.2.12.Final`

It is available in Maven Central, as you can [see here](https://search.maven.org/artifact/io.undertow/undertow-servlet-jakartaee9/2.2.12.Final/jar).
Weld 4 is actually using precisely this artifact, which can be seen from [pom.xml](https://github.com/weld/core/blob/4.0.2.Final/environments/servlet/core/pom.xml#L139-L142).

This should be the missing part in your puzzle.

Comment: thanks, it helps. I by excluding undertow-servlet and adding the other one, I get a bit further. 
    testImplementation ('org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-undertow:5.0.0.Beta1'){
        exclude module: 'undertow-servlet'
    }
    testImplementation 'io.undertow:undertow-servlet-jakartaee9:2.2.12.Final' But now, it fails with a similar error further, complaining that org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServlet30Dispatcher (from resteasy-core 5.0.0.Beta, implements javax.servlet.Servlet and not jakarta.servlet.Servlet .. it's a never ending story, right ?

Comment: Well, IMO you'll need a different version of `resteasy-undertow` as well, e.g. some that uses `jakarta` namespace. However, that's outside of my knowledge so I cannot give you a definite answer.